# Why is event listener calling *ngIf method of child component?

Tags: angular, angular-template

Please have a look at the following code

```
<div id="safetyDiv" (scroll)="onScrollSafety()">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index;">
      <div *ngIf="foo()">{{message}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Why does scrolling the `safetyDiv` call `foo()`? I am guessing it has something to do with change detection. For testing purposes I removed the scroll event listener and then `foo()` is not called when scrolling. However in my case I need to be informed of the scroll event.
So is there a way where I can listen to the scroll event without it always calling `foo()`?

Also you can have a look at a stackblitz I created showing the described behavior: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rotj54

Comment: function calls in templates are bad practice and should be avoided for this reason.  foo depends on something so rather than having a function call, just set a property called foo when that dependency changes.

Comment: Do you know that with this you you provide a huge memory leak ?
Please make things simple and so clean code fast and to not reproduce memory leak.

Comment: The posted example is very simplified to clearly illustrate my question. Now in reality I am using the `*ngIf` to distinguish between different types. Because the messages array uses a union type and depending on the type of `message` I then insert a different component.

Comment: I updated the hello.component.ts in my stackblitz with pseudo code to illustrate what I would now do. Is that a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

tipically if you iterate over an array of objects

```
messages.forEach(x=>x.foo=this.foo(x))
//and use <div *ngIf="message.foo">
```

If is an array of string or number use a auxiliar variable

```
foos=messages.map(x=>this.foo(x))
//and use <div *ngIf="foos[i]>
```